# Convexity of $x^a$ using the first order convexity conditions

Tags: convex-analysis

I can't seem to finish the proof that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$ (strictly positive reals) and $\{a \in \mathbb{R} | a \leq 0 \text{ or } a \geq 1\}$, $f(x) = x^a$ is convex *using the first order convexity condition* *.

**My work so far:**

Assume $x, y \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$ and $x < y$. Then we need
\begin{align}
y^a &\geq x^a + ax^{a-1}(y-x)\\
y^a &\geq x^a + ayx^{a-1} - ax^a\\
(y/x)^a &\geq 1 + a(y/x) - a && (\text{$x$ is positive})\\
r^a &\geq 1 + a(r - 1)
\end{align}
with $r > 1$ because $y > x$.

**Where I need help:**

If $a = 0$ or $a = 1$, there's equality. For $a > 1$, $r^a$ is exponential in $a$ with $r > 1$ while $1 + a(r-1)$ is linear in $a$. Thus, as $a$ increases, it should be the case that $exponential > linear$. How can I make this intuition more rigorous?

I'm not sure how to handle the $a < 0$ case.

---

*First order convexity condition (in one dimension) that I'm working with is that a function $f$ is convex iff its domain is convex and the following inequality holds for all $x, y \in dom(f)$:
$f(y) \geq f(x) + f'(x)(y - x)$.

Comment: For positive integer $a$, use the binomial theorem. For general $a$, use the Mean Value Theorem: There exists a $c \in [x,y]$ such that $\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=f'(c)$